# Include managed static resource in Vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, static-resources

I have installed a managed package that has some static resources along with other features.
I want to include a static resource to my vf page, but i get an error message:
"Error: Field $cscfga__Resource.jQuery_min does not exist. Check spelling"

I declare the static resources as follows:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$cscfga__Resource.jQuery_min}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$cscfga__Resource.cs_messaging}" />
```

And i have checked that spelling is correct. What could be going wrong?

Comment: You have the namespace in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks David!!!